# show/hide textbox based on yes/no

Tags: javascript, jquery, wildcard

I have a survey, 30+ yes/no questions(radiobutton); if choose no, show textbox to give reason, and this textbox is required if choose no. I can't do it one by one. How to use wildcard and loop to do this.

```
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td width="600px">question 1?</td>
    <td width="65px">
        <asp:RadioButton ID="rdM1Y" runat="server" Text="Yes" GroupName="rdM1" />
        <asp:RadioButton ID="rdM1N" runat="server" Text="No" GroupName="rdM1" />
    </td>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtCM1" runat="server" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td width="600px">question 2?</td>
    <td width="65px">
        <asp:RadioButton ID="rdM2Y" runat="server" Text="Yes" GroupName="rdM2" />
        <asp:RadioButton ID="rdM2N" runat="server" Text="No" GroupName="rdM2" />
    </td>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtCM2" runat="server" /></td>
</tr>
```

**I need validate those textboxs isrequired if they choose no**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, so:

include jQuery (makes it all way easier):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

add `radNo` class for all "NO" radio buttons:

```
<asp:RadioButton class="radNo" ID="rdM2N" runat="server" Text="No" GroupName="rdM2" />
```

add `txtNo` class for all textboxes:

```
<asp:TextBox class="txtNo" ID="txtCM2" runat="server" />
```

add script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('.radNo').click(function(){
        var c = $(this).is(':checked');
        $(this).parents('tr').find('txtNo').toggle(c);
        if (c) {
            $(this).parents('tr').find('txtNo').focus();
        }
    });

    // validate that there's text if select NO
    $('.txtNo').bind('blur', function(){
        if ($(this).val().length < 1) {
            $(this).focus(); 
            alert('please provide a reason');
        }
    });       
});
</script>
```

that should do it, hope i understood well and it's helpful.

Comment: Thanks. But how to do the validation for the textbox if they choose no?

Comment: i'll add in my answer

Comment: Thanks Gal. The validation works. But how to handle if user accidentally click no, they don't want give reason. I should let he click yes for same question without giving reason. help please

Answer (score 0):

Generated HTML - note the `textarea` ID equals the `radio` button name

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td width="600px">question 1?</td>
    <td width="65px">
        <label><input type="radio" name="rdM1" /> Yes</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="rdM1" class="give_reason" /> No</label>
    </td>
    <td><textarea id="rdM1" name="rdM1-reason"></textarea></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
textarea {display: none;}
```

Javascript

```
$(document).on('click', 'input:radio', function(){
   el = $('#' + this.name); 
   ($(this).hasClass('give_reason'))? el.show() : el.hide(); 
});
```

[DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/UT9yN/)

Answer (score 0):

First give no-radiobuttons a common class, for example say it "noRadio". Then, you can listen click events of all radio buttons with this class. Within the event handler function you can find the corresponding text box and show it. My sample code is below:

```
$(".noRadio").click(function(e) {
    // get id of the clicked radio button
    var id = $(e.target).attr("id");
    // remove "rdM" and "N" from id and get pure question number
    id = id.replace("rdM", "").replace("N", "");
    // select the corresponding text box by its id, e.g. "#txtCM2" if "#rdM2N" selected
    $("#txtCM" + id).show();
});
```

I tried this approach in my projects and it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', 'input:radio', function(){
$('table').each(function(){
if($('input[type= radio]:checked').val() == no)) 
{
    $('textbox').show();
}
});

  });
```